# AspNetCore Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerResponseAttribute'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have ASP.NET Core Web application where I am using swagger using the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
        c.OperationFilter<DescriptionOperationFilter>();
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "API",
            Description = "",
        });
        // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API"); });
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

When I navigate to url/swagger I am getting the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HLG1T7PRT05H", Request id: An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerResponseAttribute' from
>   assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral'.at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples.DescriptionOperationFilter.SetResponseModelDescriptions(Operation
>   operation, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription
>   apiDescription)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples.DescriptionOperationFilter.Apply(Operation
>   operation, OperationFilterContext context)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreateOperation(ApiDescription
>   apiDescription, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1
>   apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItems(IEnumerable`1
>   apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String
>   documentName, String host, String basePath, String[] schemes)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application)

The nuget packages I installed are:

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v3.0.0

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples v2.9.0

Comment: Hope so, it might help https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/855

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rolling back Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to v2.5.0 did the trick

Answer (score 16):

Uninstalling the package

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples
```

should fix the issue. The new package is (haven't tried this yet)-

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters
```

**(UPDATE)**
The new package works perfectly fine

Answer (score 6):

this worked for us, while upgrading to .netcore 3.0:

1) Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 5.0.0-rc4

2) change code to

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPI", Version = "v1" });
                });
        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "swagger/ui";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI(v1)");
        });
        ...
    }
```

basically, following samples found at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc4

Comment: Worked for me in .netcore 3.0

Answer (score 2):

This related to several breaking changes in version 3. [Here you can find more information.](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/799)

To fix this try to add [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/)

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations -Version 3.0.0
```

For dotnet core:

```
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations --version 3.0.0
```

Detailed [Release Notes For v3.0.0](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

To make it work on later versions and in ASPNET Core you need to:

1. reference nuget Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters
2. within `AddSwaggerGen` call `ExampleFilters();` (in ConfigureServices)
3. implement your example class based on `IExampleProvider<TargetDtoType>` where `TargetDtoType` is your target type of your example
4. call `AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<ExampleTypeImplementation>` where ExampleTypeImplementation is the type from step 3 that implements `IExampleProvider<TargetDtoType>`

This did the trick for me. No need for any action method attributes, swashbuckle picks up via the parameter type and automatically generates the examples

Comment: Also need to make sure that the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples package is not included.