# Exception when adding swagger with .NET Core 3.0

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to integrate swagger into a `ASP NET Core 3.0` project and it throws exception right in the `ConfigureServices` method:

I am using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` 4.0.1.

I have also checked this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842808/aspnetcore-could-not-load-type-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-swaggergen-swaggerrespons/51843217) and also [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1259)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = " API",
                    Description="API for the  Server",
                });

            });
        }
```

**Exception**

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator': Failed to compare two elements in the array.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaRegistryFactory Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaRegistryFactory': Failed to compare two elements in the array.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at SXS.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Work\SXS\SXS\Core\Server\SXS.Server\Program.cs:line 32

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator': Failed to compare two elements in the array.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.

Inner Exception 3:
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

**P.S**  I have followed this [guide](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/clean-way-to-add-swagger-asp-net-core-application/) and the only difference is that while he uses a `OpenApiInfo` object i do not have that overload available and thus am using a `Info`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just went through [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) at learn.microsoft.com and had no problem.

The docs explain you need to use the *latest* preview version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore,   5.0.0-rc4

Answer (score 59):

I experienced this issue, using .Net Core 3.1.2 and Swagger 5.4.1.

Turns out I forgot to add `services.AddControllers();` to my `Startup::ConfigureServices` method.

I was only adding Razor Pages.

Comment: This was also true for me in .Net Core 5.0.0-preview.4

Comment: In Core 3.1 and Swagger 5.5.1 I had to add `services.AddControllers();` and also `endpoints.MapControllers();`.

Comment: The `ASP.NET Core documentation` seems to indicate that `AddControllers();` and maybe `AddEndpointsApiExplorer();` should be enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error with Minimamal API.

I added `builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();` to `Program.cs` and it was fine.

this was in dotnet 7

Comment: also worked in dotnet 6

Comment: This worked for me as well, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to usage of wrong swagger package and as a result the Info api is using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info which caused the problem.

If you use the latest Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, 5.0.0-rc4m package then it will take OpenApiInfo from new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models and then it will work.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

The logs wouldn't tell me the answer I had to open up the swagger generated  JSON File

```
http://localhost:{PORT}/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "My API",
                Description = "My API description for blah blah"
            });
        });
```

Btw I'm using .Net Core 2.1